# rake aborted! ExecJS::RuntimeError: (execjs):1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, maskedinput

I'm getting an error while precompiling on production server; however, if I set the environment as **production** and run the precompilation on the **development** computer, it runs ok. How can it be possible?

```
RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

error returned:

```
   ...
   rake aborted!
   ExecJS::RuntimeError:
   (execjs):1
   ...
```

I have no clue whatsoever on where's the error coming from.

Comment: I understand what you say about depending on people updating gems, but have you considered using [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/)? The gems are generated automatically, so technically you don't depend on any specific maintainer, and you get updates using Bundler as for all other gems.

Comment: @taglia Yes. You're right. It's a good approach. Thanks for the note man!

Comment: @taglia I did convert my assets to rails-assets; however, the error was on falling short of RAM memory on the production server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply: My production server was running out of RAM memory. I boosted it a little bit to 1GB and now it works like a charm!

Comment: Ditto.  I was using cap to deploy a rails app, and found i had to kill the app before running deploy.  Just run htop on the server and see how close you get to the maxing out RAM.

Comment: Unfortunately 512mb won't do even for a staging server!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and restarting the server it solve it.

**EDIT**

Also you can add swap. Here is a great tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.My server was ngnix. After restart using command

```
service nginx restart
```

solved the problem.